# Unexpected keyword argument when working with several objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to work with severals objects to achieve an action.

**My models.py**

```
 class LogBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    
class LogMessage(models.Model):
    logbook = models.ForeignKey(LogBook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class LogDone(models.Model):
    logmessage = models.ForeignKey(LogMessage)
    done_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**My view :**

```
def logmessage_done(request, logmessage_id, log_id, token ):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
    logmessages = LogMessage.objects.filter(logbook=log)
    logdone = LogDone.objects.get_or_create(logmessage=logmessages)
    logdone.done_status = True
    logdone.update()
```

**My url :**

```
"done/<int:logmessage_id>/<int:log_id>/<str:token>"
```

**What I want to achieve :**

I want to change the status of the **logdone object** which is link to the **logmessage object** but I am not sure I have access object correctly.

**What error I have :**

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to the correct view?

Comment: Sorry it is a different error code, I have updated my view. 
Please note that I have tried many answer from SO and open a question 1 week ago but was not able to make it work.

Comment: `LogDone.objects.get_or_create(logmessage=logmessages)` does not make any sense, since you can not assign a *collection* of `LogMessage`s to a `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your view like this:

```
def logmessage_done(request, logmessage_id, log_id, token ):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
    logmessages = LogMessage.objects.filter(logbook=log)
    for log_message in logmessages:
       LogDone.objects.update_or_create(logmessage=log_message,defaults={"done_status": True})
```

Here , log returns a single object with id . logmessages returns a queryset with logbook = the log returned in first query. Have to use update_or_create method

Comment: For some reason now it gives me the following error : > ERROR: NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint on the column logmessage_id